# Passing Multiple Selected Value in Single ? Parameter in MS Reporting Services (SQL Server 2008) against an ODBC data source

Tags: odbc, parameter-passing, selected

I am attempting to change an old report that uses an ODBC data source.

The change I am making is to change the Query to accept a multi-parameter assignment that is passed in through the ? variable.

But ANY attempt to change the query to look for a Multi-Value scenario result in an error.

In other words, it seems like when you are using an ODBC connection, it MUST BE a 1:1 comparison (VariableName=?)

[Variable Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mf0u.jpg)

I've tried CHARINDEX & POSITION IN